# How to tag specific images?

Tags: xml, adobe-indesign, extendscript

I'd like to tag specific inline images in my document but am a but stuck on the actual tagging part. What I already have is the following :

```
var myDoc = app.activeDocument;
var myItems = myDoc.allPageItems;
var foundInlineImages = Array();

// loop through the page and find all inline objects (images).
// Name has to be Rectangle to exclude grouped objects.

for(var i = 0, len = myItems.length; i < len; i++)
{
    if( (myItems[i].constructor.name=="Rectangle") && (myItems[i].parent instanceof Character) )
    {
        foundInlineImages.push(myItems[i]);
    }
}


// encapsulate all array entries with [Image] tag

for(var i = 0; i < foundInlineImages.length; i++)
{
   // I need here something like foundInlineImages[i].changeTextPreferences.markupTag="Image";
   // unfortunatly this doesn't work ...
}
```

Can somebody lead me to the right syntax to encapsulate each found object in my array with a tag (in this case 'image') ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

@Wokoman -- To encapsulate an image with an XML tag as you are saying:

> - first create an XML tag named "Image" for each image
> - create an XML element from that tag
> - then insert each image into the XML element

You are trying to change a property of an Image object, but  `Image`  does not have the properties  `changeTextPreference.markupTag`  (see [InDesign object model --> Image](http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs5js/pc_Image.html) for reference).

 `Application`  has these properties  `changeTextPreference.markupTag` (see [InDesign object model --> changeTextPreference](http://jongware.mit.edu/idcsjs5.5/pc_ChangeTextPreference.html) for reference).

---

So, try this out (**this is untested**, and based on p. 168 of [InDesignCS5_ScriptingGuide_JS](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/products/indesign/pdfs/InDesignCS5_ScriptingGuide_JS.pdf)):

```
var xmlImageTag = "";
var xmlImageElement = "";

for(var i = 0, len = foundInlineImages.length; i < len; i++)
{
    // each Image tag created here
    xmlImageTag = myDoc.xmlTags.add("Image");

    // each Image element created here, from the Image tag
    xmlImageElement = myDoc.xmlElements.item(i).xmlElements.add(xmlImageTag);

    // inserting each image into each new Image element
    xmlImageElement.contents = foundInlineImages[i];
}
```